# How to hide option "Show All" on portfolio istope

Tags: javascript, java, wordpress, filter

I want to hide the option "Show All" on portfolio i want to show just the categories. you can check it here   [WEBPAGE](http://www.zwickypartner.ch/?page_id=76)
should i go with this code :

```
    jQuery( function( $ ) { 

$("nav.filters li:first a").css("display","none");

setTimeout(function() {
 $("nav.filters li:nth-child(2) a").addClass("filterSelected").click() }, 1

000);

});
```

or can anyone add a custome CSS code .

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any JS/jQuery code to hide that. Just use the following CSS

```
#filters li:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

And if you want to apply the first category filtering then the following jQuery code can help you

```
setTimeout( function() {
    $('#filters li:nth-child(2) a').addClass('filterSelected').click();
}, 1000 );
```

***Note:*** I found filter nav id is `#filters` on your given link

Answer (score 0):

thank you.  i have tryed this code

```
#filters li:first-child a, .filter li:first-child {
    display:none
}
```

Know to apply the first category filtering i try ur code in jquery.isotope.min.js# or in wich file i have to add your code exactly..
thankyou verymuch.

Comment: can you tell me in wich line i have to add the jsquery code

Comment: ?? hello anybody here